# How to add strings to a list in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of values that looks like this:

```
15,100,25.0
-50,-50,50.0
-20,120,70,40
200,-100,25,5
```

The first two lines represent values for a circle, the third for a rectangle and the fourth for a polygon. I would like the output to look like this:

```
c 15,100,25.0
c -50,-50,50.0
r -20,120,70,40
p 200,-100,25,5
```

I'm not sure how I can add the letter for each of the lines. I have a for-loop that I'm using to go through the information in the string to print them out.

```
for shapes in list_of_shapes:
    print(",".join(str(item) for item in shapes))
```

Here's some of my code:

```
list_of_shapes = []

while p >= 0:

    #Here is a bunch of code

    list_of_shapes.append("c")
    list_of_shapes.append(circle) # appends the data for the circles
while p2 >= 0:
    #bunch of code
    list_of_shapes.append("r")
    list_of_shapes.append(rect) # appends the data for the rectangle
while p3 >= 0:
    #code
    list_of_shapes.append("p")
    list_of_shapes.append(poly) # appends the data for the polygon

    return list_of_shapes
```

Once I do this for all of them, I end up getting:

```
c
15,100,25.0
c
-50,-50,50.0
r
-20,120,70,40
p
200,-100,25,5
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in here:

```
while p >= 0:

    #Here is a bunch of code

    list_of_shapes.append("c")
    list_of_shapes.append(circle) # appends the data for the circles
while p2 >= 0:
    #bunch of code
    list_of_shapes.append("r")
    list_of_shapes.append(rect) # appends the data for the rectangle
while p3 >= 0:
    #code
    list_of_shapes.append("p")
    list_of_shapes.append(poly) # appends the data for the polygon

    return list_of_shapes
```

This gives you `['c', <circle>, 'r', <rect>, 'p', <poly>]`. You could do this:

```
while p >= 0:

    #Here is a bunch of code
    list_of_shapes.append(("c", circle)) # appends the data for the circles
while p2 >= 0:
    #bunch of code
    list_of_shapes.append(("r", rect)) # appends the data for the rectangle
while p3 >= 0:
    #code
    list_of_shapes.append(("p", poly)) # appends the data for the polygon

    return list_of_shapes
```

This basically pairs each shape with its classification. Then you can print by doing this:

```
for shape_type, shape in list_of_shapes:
    print("{} {}".format(shape_type, ",".join(str(item) for item in shapes)))
```

Answer (score 4):

What you're doing is just adding extra strings to the list, rather than appending/prepending to the strings themselves.

From your code above, you could probably do this, if you just wanted a list of strings:

```
list_of_shapes = []

while p >= 0:

    #Here is a bunch of code

    list_of_shapes.append("c {0}".format(','.join(circle))) # append data for circles by converting the circle list into a string
while p2 >= 0:
    #bunch of code
    list_of_shapes.append("r {0}".format(','.join(rect))) # append data for rect by converting the rect list into a string
while p3 >= 0:
    #code
    list_of_shapes.append("p {0}".format(','.join(poly))) # append data for polygon by converting the poly list into a string

return list_of_shapes
```

You would then just print this list out like this:

```
for shape in list_of_shapes: print(shape)
```

Note that in all `while` blocks, you now only execute `list_of_shapes.append` once.

This uses [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) which allows you to format a string a specific way.

However, if you want to retain all the list data separately (rather than make it entirely a string), something like what Snakes and Coffee suggests would work.

Answer (score 0):

To append your desired letter to list you can do:

```
list = [15,100,25.0]
list_with_letter = ["c"] + list
```